# Why is it recommended to change the jdk after long use?

Tags: java

When I was first learning java from a crash course, we were advised by the teacher to change the jdk after long use.

While she couldn't provide any scientific explanation to this, even I find it necessary to change the jdk at points of time. In the computer at my home, sometimes it happens that a program that I've written, is syntactically, semantically and logically correct, but both BlueJ and NetBeans give unexplained compilation or run-time error. Both BlueJ and NetBeans run on the same jdk.

If I download a new jdk package and install it, removing the previous one, it solves the problem.

Can anyone explain this?

Comment: [Bit rot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_rot)?

Comment: Maybe. I don't know the reason. But that link properly explains what I was asking.

Comment: I rather doubt that this question will receive much positive reactions. Problems on the "re-install the JDK to fix it" are most likely not in the scope of this community. My personal two cents: I have not seem something like this in years.

Answer (score 1):

New versions of the JDK can run old code, but the opposite is not necessarily true: Recent applications will take advantage of recent features of the JDK, and will not be compatible with older versions.

Note that sometimes, applications built with some JDK may not run with newer versions. For instance, JDK 7 has removed some deprecated classes from JDK1.6.

Comment: Also some variable names may become reserved keywords, e.g `enum` in JDK 1.5 .

Comment: @Berger Yes, but it doesn't affect the code that is already compiled.